# Configuring "writeToDisk" in Webpack Encore

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-encore, webpack-5

Intuitively, I'd think that the `writeToDisk` option could be configured under `configureDevServerOptions`, but trying to do so yields this error:

```
Running webpack-dev-server ...

 WARNING  Webpack is already provided by Webpack Encore, also adding it to your package.json file may cause issues.
 WARNING  Passing an absolute URL to setPublicPath() *and* using the dev-server can cause issues. Your assets will load from the publicPath (http://localhost:9091/build/) instead of from the dev server URL.
[webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'writeToDisk'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, setupExitSignals?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

The value has also been attempted to be set through the `getWebpackConfig()` object, but the same error gets generated.

The next way to attack this could then be through `devMiddleware` due to [this `writeToDisk` option](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#writetodisk). This produces this error:

```
Running webpack-dev-server ...

 WARNING  Webpack is already provided by Webpack Encore, also adding it to your package.json file may cause issues.
 WARNING  Passing an absolute URL to setPublicPath() *and* using the dev-server can cause issues. Your assets will load from the publicPath (http://localhost:9091/build/) instead of from the dev server URL.
  TypeError: Cannot set property 'writeToDisk' of undefined

  - webpack.config.js:99 Object.<anonymous>
    C:/path/to/project/webpack.config.js:99:41

  - apply-options-callback.js:13 module.exports
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/utils/apply-options-callback.js:13:36

  - config-generator.js:616 ConfigGenerator.buildDevServerConfig
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:616:16

  - config-generator.js:60 ConfigGenerator.getWebpackConfig
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:60:74

  - config-generator.js:631 module.exports
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:631:22

  - index.js:1634 Encore.getWebpackConfig
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/index.js:1634:16

  - EncoreProxy.js:51 Proxy.minDistance
    [project]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/EncoreProxy.js:51:53

  - webpack.config.js:126 Object.<anonymous>
    C:/path/to/project/webpack.config.js:126:25

  - v8-compile-cache.js:192 Module._compile
    [project]/[v8-compile-cache]/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30

  - loader:1153 Object.Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Since `publicPath` is not in this dev server "schema," I have had to set the public path through `setPublicPath` to the value in the warning, causing that warning to be generated.

The first warning is from setting my `package.json` Webpack definition to `webpack@^5.35` so other dependency warnings are not generated.

How can options not defined in the dev server schema be properly configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `copyFiles` function by just ensuring the whole build directory gets copied over in the `dev-server` environment.